# Finding a sphere tangent to 3 other spheres

Tags: linear-algebra

So it's been a long time I didn't practice and I find myself stuck with that problem...

I have three spheres, of known position and radius. I'm looking to find the position of a 4th sphere (of known radius), so it is tangent to the first three spheres.

I just have no clue of where to start. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Given the radius of the fourth sphere...?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really have no idea of where I can go with that. It's probably obvious but I'm very rusty

Comment: I found your topic searching myself a solution for some physic research, you will find the answer to your problem here : https://axiomatic.neophilus.net/clustering-tangent-spheres/ Good luck !!

Comment: He's asking whether or not you're given the radius of the 4th sphere - your wording makes it seem like you already have the radius, so it's a little ambiguous. You have a radius for a 4th sphere, and you want to find a position such that the 4th sphere is tangent, correct?